# MySQL update using subquery, error 1093

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I tried searching here, but no luck. Nothing appear to be the same problem.

I have this select:

```
SELECT a.whse, a.sku, a.data, a.dt_exp FROM volume_hist_fin a
WHERE a.data = (
  SELECT MAX(b.data)
  FROM volume_hist_fin b
  WHERE b.md5_skuwhse = a.md5_skuwhse
 )
GROUP BY whse, sku, a.data
```

It works. I'm trying now to do the update. This update:

```
UPDATE volume_hist_fin a SET a.dt_exp = '2013-10-09'
WHERE a.data = (
  SELECT MAX(b.data) 
  FROM volume_hist_fin b
  WHERE b.md5_skuwhse = a.md5_skuwhse
 )
```

But I'm getting the error:

> 1093 "You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause"

All the problem it's that the subquery need to get the max data using the same id code (md5_skuwhse)

How can I make this update work?

Comment: Can you try this-->UPDATE volume_hist_fin SET dt_exp = '2013-10-09'
WHERE data = (
  SELECT MAX(b.data) 
  FROM volume_hist_fin b
  WHERE b.md5_skuwhse = md5_skuwhse
 )

Comment: Thanks @Gayathri. Did not try you answer, I used the answer from peterm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `JOIN`

```
UPDATE volume_hist_fin a JOIN
(
  SELECT md5_skuwhse, MAX(data) max_data
    FROM volume_hist_fin
   GROUP BY md5_skuwhse
) b
    ON a.md5_skuwhse = b.md5_skuwhse
   AND a.data = b.max_data
   SET a.dt_exp = '2013-10-09'
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked, well not it all. The first one gave me an error "Unknown column 'a.md5_skuwhse' in 'where clause'" the second one there as a missing 'b' on the alias, I edited and it worked :) Thanks.

Comment: In a version with `JOIN` a table alias `b` in the subquery is unnecessary. But the subquery itself has an alias of `b`.

Comment: does not work without the alias, it says "Unknown column 'b.data' in 'field list'" , that's why I added the alias inside. Worked with it

Comment: Sorry. It's a typo in `MAX()`. I fixed it. It just left from a version with a subquery.